# How to pass types from a generic method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a generic method that it takes a type T of a `sapclient` method but when I want to initialize it, it initializes as object instead of the actual class. How is it possible to initialize it and pass the username and password as it requires it?

```
public static Auth<T>(string username, string password) where T : new()
{
    T client = new T(binding, endpointAddress)
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password
}
```

I tried that code but it always gives an error saying

> cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T'

Comment: There's no easy way to achieve this without Reflection. Can you use an interface with a `Create` method or pass a `Func<T, string, string>` to the method to create `T` outside? There are other ways, of course, depending on the constraints you have

Comment: What is the purpose of the generic type argument? What are the possible values for `T`? Would I be allowed to call `Auth<string>(uid,pwd)`?

Comment: This cannot currently be done in C#. The parameterless form of a constructor is the only one that's currently supported by the [`new` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint). There are various flavors of work-arounds, but to help you figure out which one is most appropriate would involve knowing a lot more about your app. The solution may involve refactoring your code to use factories and such.

Comment: Your method is missing a return type

Answer (score -1):

You haven't guaranteed that type `T` has a constructor with two arguments of whatever types `binding` and `endpointAddress` are. Your `new()` constraint ensures that `T` will have a constructor with *no* arguments, but says nothing about any other constructors or lack thereof.

For example, it's valid to call your method, as it is defined, as such: `Auth<int>("username", "password")`, since `int` is a value type (and all value types inherently have a parameterless constructor which initializes all of their fields to their default values). But `int` doesn't have a constructor with two arguments. This contradiction is why your code won't compile.

I don't think it's possible, in general, to call a non-empty constructor on a generic type. Constructors aren't inherited and there are no other ways to constrain constructors aside from the `new()` constraint. Are you sure you want to be using generics?